# How to select and remove entire text from text box input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know we can set a text box value like `.val('');` but in my case I need some how delete/Remove the existing value from the input by selecting and deleting. Now I am able to select the value, but how can I remove or delete it?

```js
$("#open-cal").on("click", function() {
  var $inbox = $('#whereItsAt');
  $inbox.select();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-default" id="open-cal" href="#" role="button">Select And Remove</button>
<br />
<br />

<input id="whereItsAt" type="text" value="$2,000,000" />
```

Comment: And `$inbox.val('');` doesn't do that?

Comment: It seems to be you just need to remove the value, can't you just set the value of the box to empty string? http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: As I said in post I know how to `$inbox.val('');` but this is not what I am looking for

Comment: What do you mean with delete/Remove()? maybe `$inbox.val('').focus();`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to copy the text into the clipboard before you remove it (i.e. *Cut*)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the selectionStart index, the selectionEnd, and then just replace that with the content you like.

In this example, I get the selected range, then replace it with an empty string, then apply it to the value of the input.

```js
$("#open-cal").on("click", function() {
  var $inbox = $('#whereItsAt');
  $inbox.select();
  
  var selectionStart = $inbox[0].selectionStart;
  var selectionEnd = $inbox[0].selectionEnd;
  
  var inputVal = $inbox.val();
  var str = inputVal.substring(selectionStart, selectionEnd)
  $inbox.val(inputVal.replace(str, ''))

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-default" id="open-cal" href="#" role="button">Select And Remove</button>
<br />
<br />

<input id="whereItsAt" type="text" value="$2,000,000" />
```

Comment: This seems to be a Rube Goldberg way of doing `$inbox.val('whatever')`, but +1 for figuring out what the OP wanted.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP wants to replace just a certain portion of the text input and that's why he's looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

If by "select" a value you mean getting the value then use same method without sending anything it will return the value:
 $('#whereItsAt').val();